# closeble images in view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to display images 10  in the view. Those images should appear in a FillLayout.VERTICAL manner. Each images should be able to close.How do I give the close button to the images?
It can look the same close button as of a view. Request you to to help me.

Thanks
paachu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible strategy could be to create `Label` controls to a top `Composite` and then add a `MouseListener` to each that will hide the view again (via `part.getSite().getPage().hideView(part)`).

Comment: ok. thanks for your reply. So I can assue that there is no other way right? Or can I create one view in another view? Is that possible?

Comment: Views within views is not supported in Eclipse 3. With some work, you can do it with Eclipse 4.

Comment: ok.then I can forget that solution. Let me try the way you suggested.thanks.